# Pasar parámetro de una vista a otra MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, linq

tengo el siguiente boton,

```
@Html.ActionLink("Agregar al carrito","addProducview", new {id = model.IdArticulo})
```

pero quiero pasar ese parametro a una nueva vista y no se como capturarlo, porque en la barra de navegacion del navegador me manda el id del producto, pero quiero que sin mostrarlo yo guardarlo en una variable para poder buscar los datos de ese producto, ayuda

Comment: Bienvenido, si no pones código no tenemos forma de saber qué puede estar pasando. Por favor, edita tu pregunta con tu código y de paso échale un vistazo a [ask], [mcve] y [tour]

Comment: No te sirve `TempData`?

Comment: lo que pasa es que tengo el id en un actionlink cuando el pulsa me pone el id del producto en el link pero lo que quiero es capturar ese id

Comment: aunque lo intente pero no me funciono

Comment: @Ing.JoseValera, sin codigo nos sera imposible ayudarte. Muestranos el codigo relevante de tu situacion para poder darte una respuesta concreta.

Comment: @Einer modifique la pregunta espero que me entiendas

Comment: percibo que recién estás aprendiendo a usar ASP.net MVC, por ello te recomiendo mirar el workshop que hice http://fredyfx.com/post/material-workshop-aspnet-mvc-5/ deseando que te sea de utilidad, te mando buenas vibras con el proyecto :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aunque no explicas si lo utilizaras en el controlador o la vista, aquí te muestro como obtener el valor id tanto en la vista como en el controlador.

En la vista seria de la siguiente manera:

```
@{
 Layout = "...";

 // obtenemos el id utilizando el objeto Request
 int id = int.Parse(Request["id"]);

// haces lo que necesites con el id;
}
```

En el contrador tienes dos maneras de hacerlo:

Por medio aun parámetro en el action:

```
public ActionResult addProducview(int id)
{
  // haces lo que necesites con el id
  //...
}
```

O con el objeto request otra vez:

```
public ActionResult addProducview()
{
   int id = int.Parse(Request["id"]);
   //...
}
```

Comment: es en el controlador que lo voy a utilizar

Comment: pero tengo una pregunta del controlador de articulo addProducview() tengo un metodo get y un mentodos post, porque en el get es que me envia el parametro pero en el metodo post es que quiero recuperarlo

Comment: A ver si entendi, estas enviando un parametro por medio a get en un metodo que esta marcado como `[HttpPost]`?

Comment: no , lo que pasa es que tengo una vista difente, que me envia el paramentro luego en el get de addproductview en la url del navegador me manda el id pero en el post no me da el parametro addproductview view como objeto y lo recupero view.idarticulo pero me lo trae null

Comment: El asuto esta en que estas juntando GET por POST. El metodo que dices: *pero en el post no me da el parametro* se entiende estas enviando aun metodo marcado como [HttpPost]. Organiza tu idea e intenta explicarte un poco mejor.

Comment: El Asunto es el siguiente tengo una vista que me da el listado de los artículos, correcto luego de hay tengo una vista que me dice que cantidad de ese producto quiero agregar hay hace el get, pero en el post cuando estoy buscando el parametro id que me aparece en la url del navegador me sale null